# Understanding the Expanded Definition of Big O Notation

Tags: big-o

I understand what Big O sets out to achieve overall - the worst case runtime of something - and its importance, but I'm confused by how it's expressed in more complicated terms. As an example (but I see similar everywhere):

> 0 <= f(n) <= c g(n) for all n>=n0

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-big-oh-big-omega-and-big-theta/

I *think* I get what f(n) is in this context: f is a function we want to test; n is the input to that function; the output of f(n) is the runtime. f and n themselves are generic placeholders for the function and the input that would be used in practice, not specifics (eg. the n in f(n) doesn't mean linear time complexity *just because* the n is n^1; it's just there to represent whatever is fed into the function, which could be (and result in) anything, in this abstract definition).

1. Is that correct so far?
2. What is the 0 at the beginning? Is that merely saying "there must be at least one line of code that runs"; i.e. simply that there's something being run to be performed in the first place?
3. What is g()? If f(n) is something I've come up with, is g() something I need to come up with too?
4. I know that c means "constant" in this context, but what constant and from where? Is it the number of instructions that are performed regardless of the input size?

Eg. if we were looking at the time complexity of the following function:

```
function example (int x){
    x = x * 2
    for (int i = 0, i <= x, i++){
        println(x);
        x += 1;
        x -= 1; // functionally arbitrary; just so I can wrap my head around it
        println("Testing");
    }
    println("I'm done now");
}
```

Would any of these lines count towards the value of c? Which? Or am I totally off the mark?

5. What is n0? No input? The smallest input? The input multiplied by 0? The first entry when input n is a zero-indexed array? Is n0 even related to n?

Once I understand what each part is, I think I can wrap my head around what is being expressed. Before then, I'm a bit lost!

Answer (score 0):

The notation is f(n) = O(g(n)) where:

- f() is the execution time of the algorithm we're studying
- n is the size or order of magnitude of the input fed of the algorithm
- g() is another function representing time

So, for example, if our algorithm results in sorting an array, f(4) would be the time it takes to sort an array of length 4. This function obviously depends not only on the algorithm and on n, but also on the particular array we feed as input. Here the "big O" comes in handy.

f(n) <= g(n) tells us that, for how unlucky we will get, execution will never exceed the value g(4). (that is, if 4>=n_0)

Now you'll notice that your formula also has a constant "c". That's only a scale factor and means that in the notation there's no difference in writing O(n) or O(100*n).

Now, to have f(n) = O(n) means that your execution time at a given n is always smaller than c*n for any given c AND for n>=n_0. For example 50*log(n) = O(n) with n_0 = 100. From n_0 onwards **f() is always smaller because it GROWS more slowly**.

The zero is there only because this refers to real algorithms that take a positive execution time.

Comment: Thank you, that's helped a lot! I think I'm closer, but there's a few things I don't understand specifically. Probably the biggest is the difference between f() and g(), especially as they both operate on n and are about runtime. Could you explain what makes them different? Is it that f() is the ACTUAL worst runtime given the specifics being tested, and g() is the HYPOTHETICAL worst runtime by looking at the magnitude of the input purely abstractly? @PaoloJ42

Comment: Secondly, if c is there to displace the scale of the input (as the magnitude is most important factor re the input), why is it only mentioned with g()? Wouldn't it appear with f() somewhere, eg. f(c*n)?

Finally, I think I'm starting to get n0, but I don't really know how to word it. It's in the diagrams on the page I linked, and shows a point where f(n) is always less than or equal to cg(n) going forward. Is it saying that, at some point, the time complexity of algorithms holds forever, but for some algorithms there may exist a few input sizes that break the expected time complexity?

Comment: Sorry if this notifies you twice; didn't include the mention in my first comment originally, and not sure how edits work! @PaoloJ42

Comment: @vfr4bgt5nhy6 I don't know if you're familiar with it but this notation shares some concepts with mathematical limits. The purpose is not to give a value that bounds the runtime when input complexity (i.e. n) gets really big, the purpose is to find an upper bound for the TIME GROWTH BEHAVIOUR when n grows. g() represents a family of functions that grow faster than f, no matter what the scale c is.

Comment: That is, n is always lower than 20*n, butthe growth is the same so it does not hold n = O(20n) while it holds n=O(n^2). The c could be on both sides of the equations c1*f...c2*g but define c=c2/c1 and you get the same.  Of course there are some very specific inputs that may greatly deviate from the modelled f(), but those are usually isolated extreme cases that are just not relevant for this kind of evaluation

Comment: @PaoloJ42 It definitely does hold that n = O(20n), as it does that 20n = O(n). f(n) = O(g(n)) means that the growth of f is less than *or equal to* the growth of g. You seem to be talking about little o, where g is strictly greater than f in the limit.

Comment: @PaoloJ42 Also, f(n) doesn't have to be less than cg(n) for *any c* above an n value n0. There just has to exist *at least one c* and n0 which make the statement true

Comment: @inodirection you're right, I got it mixed, I wrote the whole reasoning with "for every c" but it's "there exists a c"

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177357/having-a-bit-of-trouble-reasoning-the-formal-definition-of-big-o/70179497#70179497) might just answer what f(n) = O(g(n)) represents conceptually, and the way that the formal definition you alluded to expresses that concept.

Directly addressing some of your points:

1. Yes, f(n) could be any function of n, where n represents the *size* of the input your algorithm, and f(n) gives the run-time of your algorithm in terms of n. Size could mean different things in different contexts, but it's whatever aspect of your input could cause the algorithm's run-time to vary. It could be the size of the array for a sorting algorithm, or the length of a the input string for a palindrome-checker, etc.
2. The 0 does just represent the fact that any valid time-complexity function, f or g, should be non-negative. No algorithm runs in negative time for any input size n.
3. Generally you say that one function f, is in the complexity class represented by another function, g. So g could really be any other function of execution time in terms of input size n. There are different kinds of complexity classes, but for "Big O", f(n) = O(g(n)) means f(n) is no more than a constant times greater than g(n) as n goes to infinity. Alternatively, you could say that f(n) doesn't grow any faster than g(n) does as n gets arbitrarily large. So, if you say that an algorithm is O(n^2), what you're claiming is that it's execution time on a given input size, f(n), doesn't exceed n^2 by more than a constant factor as n gets arbitrarily large.

For example, let's say you have an algorithm that performs 2 operations on each element of an input array you pass to it (a multiplication and then an assignment to a result array):

```js
function squareValues(array) {
  let result = [];
  for (let [i, value] of array.entries()) {
    let squaredValue = value * value;
    result[i] = squaredValue;
  }
  return result; 
}
console.log(squareValues([1,2,3,4]));
```

You could represent this algorithm's runtime as a function of input size as f(n) = 2n, where n is the length of the array (it performs 2 operations for every element of the input array). You could be more precise and say that f(n) = 2n + 2, as it really does 2 additional operations each time it runs (creating the result array in the first line and then returning it in the last line), but this wouldn't turn out to impact its Big O complexity class.

You could then say that f(n) = O(n) (here g(n) = n), because f(n)=2n doesn't grow faster than g(n)=n as n goes to infinity (2n stay within a constant multiple, 2, of n as n goes to infinity). We could also say that f(n) = 2n + 2 is in O(n), because as n gets arbitrarily large, f(n)=2n+2 is still approximately only 2 times greater than g(n)=n. Similarly you could say that f(n) = O(n^2), because 2n doesn't grow faster than n^2 as n gets arbitrarily large (n^2 grows faster than 2n as n goes to infinity).

4. (and 5:) The constant c in the formal definition relates to the idea that the statement f(n) = O(g(n)) says that f grows no more than a constant factor faster than g as goes to infinity. Saying f(n) <= cg(n) for all n >= n0 is another way of saying that f(n) grows no more than a constant multiple (c times) faster than g(n) as n goes to infinity. The for all n >= n0 part of the definition is just a way of saying that the statement is true as n goes to infinity (because it's true for all n greater than or equal to some particular n value n0).

Using our example, f(n) = 2n + 2, g(n) = n. f(n) = O(g(n)) because

```
2n+2 <= 3n for all n > 4
```

We're showing that f(n)=2n+2 grows no more than a constant times faster than g(n)=n as n goes to infinity using c=3 and n0=4. Because f(n) is less than 3 times g(n) for every n value greater than 4, f(n) grows no more than a constant times (3 times) faster than g(n) as n goes to infinity. Therefore f(n) = O(g(n)): 2n+2 = O(n). You would then say that our algorithm, whose runtime we represented in terms of input array length n as f(n)=2n+2, is O(n).